# File system operation validation at C standard library level

Tags: c, testing, libc, test-suite

I'm implementing an alternative C standard library with file operation support.

I'm planning to support both:

- [file stream API](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-on-Streams.html#I_002fO-on-Streams) like fopen, fwrite and etc.
- [low level file API](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-I_002fO.html#Low_002dLevel-I_002fO) like open, write and etc.

I'm looking for a test suite which validates my implementation against standard C requirements (example: validates that pread returns zero when the caller requests read beyond the file contents).

I'll be happy for your suggestions.

Comment: So you are asking if anyone knows a test suite for your not yet implemented library? Seems rather off topic

Comment: I assume that people wrote other implementations of standard C library before me ;-)
I'm asking about reuse of test code since the API is there for more than 25 years...

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/posix/tst-preadwrite.c

The problem that this is not comprehensive